# Running appium script throw error pointing to older java version, which is not a currently installed version

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

Hi Running below script display below error, Please provide solution if you have faced similar issue :- 
**Script :-**

```
package com.appium.android;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class LaunchApp {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException{
           DesiredCapabilities capabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();
           capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
           capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
           //capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","4.3");
           //capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","GT-I9300");
           capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","5.1");
           capabilities.setCapability("devic`enter code here`eName","MotoG");

           capabilities.setCapability("app","C:\\Users\\ssin22\\Downloads\\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk");
           capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","io.selendroid.testapp");
           capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","io.selendroid.testapp.HomeScreenActivity");
           AndroidDriver driver=new AndroidDriver(new
           URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities); } }
```

---

**Error**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could
>   not be created. (Original error: 'java -version' failed. Error:
>   Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "java -version"
>   Error: could not open `C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre1.5.0_05\lib\i386\jvm.cfg' ) (WARNING: The server did
>   not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Looks like your path contains the wrong path to the java installation dir.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable value and try again. If the variable is correct, it should work.